# How to have same color for all buttons previous to active button and same for all buttons next to active one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble in styling buttons. What I need is that, active button and all buttons previous to active have same color, and all buttons next to active one have some other color.
is this possible to achieve in javascript?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
.mystyle{
    background-color:gold;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
  
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    
  }
  this.className += " active";
  this.previousSibling.className += " mystyle";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need any JavaScript at all. Just use the `:active` pseudo-class with the adjacent-element and sibling-element selectors in CSS.

Comment: Alright! I used :active~button to target all the adjacent buttons of active class and it works fine but how to target previous buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helped you.

```js
function removeClasses() {
  for(var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    $('#'+i+'').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+i+'').removeClass('mystyle');
    $('#'+i+'').removeClass('next');
  }
}

function activeButton(id) {
  id = parseInt(id);
  
  removeClasses();
  
  $('#'+id+'').addClass('active');
  for(var j=1;j<=(id-1);j++) $('#'+j+'').addClass('mystyle');
  for(var j=(id+1);j<=5;j++) $('#'+j+'').addClass('next');
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
.mystyle{
    background-color:gold;
}
.next {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>
  
<div id="myDIV">
  <button id="1" onclick="activeButton(this.id)" class="btn">1</button>
  <button id="2" onclick="activeButton(this.id)" class="btn">2</button>
  <button id="3" onclick="activeButton(this.id)" class="btn">3</button>
  <button id="4" onclick="activeButton(this.id)" class="btn">4</button>
  <button id="5" onclick="activeButton(this.id)" class="btn">5</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work dynamically for you

```js
let buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.demo')];

buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    buttons.map(el => {
        el.classList.remove('active');
        el.classList.remove('prev');
    }
    );
    el.classList.add('active');
    buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.demo')];
    const activeButton = buttons.find(el => el.classList.contains('active'));
    let previousSibling = activeButton.previousElementSibling;

    while (previousSibling) {
        previousSibling.classList.add('prev');
        previousSibling = previousSibling.previousElementSibling;
    }
}));
```

```css
    .demo {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        margin: 0.125rem;
        background: rgb(214, 230, 243);
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .demo.active {
        background: rgb(205, 236, 226);
    }

    .demo.prev {
        background: rgb(205, 236, 226);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="buttons">
        <div class="demo">Button 1</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 2</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 3</div>
        <div class="demo active">Button 4</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 5</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 6</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 7</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 8</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 9</div>
</div>
```

```js
        let buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.demo')];

        buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
            buttons.map(el => {
                el.classList.remove('active');
                el.classList.remove('prev');
            }
            );
            el.classList.add('active');
            buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.demo')];
            const activeButton = buttons.find(el => el.classList.contains('active'));
            // const activeButtonIndex = buttons.indexOf(activeButton);
            let previousSibling = activeButton.previousElementSibling;

            while (previousSibling) {
                previousSibling.classList.add('prev');
                previousSibling = previousSibling.previousElementSibling;
            }
        }));
```

```css
.demo {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        margin: 0.125rem;
        background: rgb(214, 230, 243);
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .demo.active {
        background: rgb(205, 236, 226);
    }

    .demo.prev {
        background: rgb(205, 236, 226);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="buttons">
        <div class="demo">Button 1</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 2</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 3</div>
        <div class="demo active">Button 4</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 5</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 6</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 7</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 8</div>
        <div class="demo">Button 9</div>
    </div>
```